# Is it possible to use two I2C interfaces with the ESP32 using micropython?

Tags: adc, i2c, esp32

I am designing an **ESP32** based board using **two ADCs** (ADS1110) having the same Address that communicate with I2C.

For that I need **two I2C** interfaces. It's mentioned in the datasheet that the ESP32 has **two** I2C interfaces.

For the first one, I am using the default ones **GPIO21** and **GPIO22**, respectively for **SDA** and **SCL**. It appears that most of the people are using those pins.

I am planning to use **GPIO32** and **GPIO33** for the second interface.

So am wondering if someone could help me with the programming using **micropython**.

**Arduino** people are using the called **"Wire"* library. But I have no idea how to make it with **micropython**. Is it possible via the the called **"machine"** library?

Comment: Part numbers (e.g. for the ADCs) would help. Also, there are ICs that can switch between multiple I2C buses for exactly the issue where multiple I2C slaves have the same address -- so you'd only need one I2C bus for your master.

Comment: Using the ADS1110 as ADCs

Comment: In the future please [edit] that information directly into the question. The [ADS1110 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1110.pdf) indicates it supports up to 8 I2C addresses -- can't you just order the variants for different addresses if you are only using two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`machine.I2C` constructor](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/machine.I2C.html#machine.I2C)

```py
class machine.I2C(id, *, scl, sda, freq=400000)
```

allows you to specify:

- the `id` of the I2C bus to use
- the pins (`scl` and `sda`)  to use

So you can just create two instances of the `I2C` class, one for each I2C bus, and use them separately, to read each of the two ADCs.

The ESP32 and associated MicroPython port does indeed support [2 hardware I2C buses, with `id`s 0 and 1](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/esp32/quickref.html#hardware-i2c-bus).

```py
from machine import Pin
from machine import I2C

i2c1 = I2C(id=0, scl=Pin(22), sda=Pin(21), freq=400000)
i2c2 = I2C(id=1, scl=Pin(32), sda=Pin(33), freq=400000)


i2c1.scan()
i2c2.scan()
i2c1.writeto(42, b'123')
i2c2.writeto(42, b'123')

etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, and in my experience - it mostly works.

I say 'mostly' because I have seen some occasional issues with the second bus reporting bogus devices present at start.

An initial `i2c2.scan()` would falsely 'find' devices with IDs all the way up to the ID of the first I2C device physically present on the bus. After that initial scan everything would function properly, but without it, the real I2C device could not be addressed.

In fairness - I was NOT using pins 32,33 for this second bus, but rather GPIO2,15 which were conveniently accessible on the ESP32 WROOM32 DevKit, so that may have been part of the observed problem.